# Python 2.7, Tkinter, make a point "trace" a waveform

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I'm trying to make a widget that demonstrates the relationship between a sine wave and it's phasor diagram. I want a pointer that follows the user's mouse movements but instead of freely moving around the page, I want it to stick to the waveform I've plotted and only follow the co-ordinates that make up that line. Kind of like a slider but along a sine wave! Any suggestions? Thanks. Here's what I've got so far;

```
import math
import Tkinter as tk
from Tkinter import PhotoImage, Canvas
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

sinwidget = tk.Tk()

main_canvas = tk.Canvas(sinwidget, width = 400, height = 400, bg= "white")
main_canvas.pack()

def callback(event):
    canvas = event.widget
    x = canvas.canvasx(event.x)
    y = canvas.canvasy(event.y)
    print canvas.find_closest(x, y)

    draw(event.x, event.y)

def draw(x, y):
    box.coords(pointer, x-20, y-20, x+20, y+20)

def exit_():
    sinwidget.destroy()

box = main_canvas
box.bind('<Motion>', callback)
box.pack()

pointer = box.create_rectangle(0.2,0.2,0.2,0.2)
wavelength = 360
height = 400
center = height//2
degree = 1
increment = 0.0175
amplitude = -80

sin = []
for x in range(360):
    sin.append(x * degree)
    sin.append(int(math.sin(x * increment) * amplitude) + center)

sinwave = main_canvas.create_line(sin, fill="red", width=2.0)

xaxis = main_canvas.create_line(0, center, wavelength, center, fill="black", 
width=3.0)

yaxis = main_canvas.create_line(2, 100, 2, 300, fill="black", width=3.0)

exit_button = tk.Button(sinwidget, text = "exit", command = exit_)

exit_button.pack()

sinwidget.mainloop()
```

Thanks for any help you can offer!